# RISC-V FENCE Instruction test

Tags: testing, riscv, instructions, riscv32

The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual in the chapter RV32I Base Integer Instruction Set specifies **fence** and **fence.i** instructions. But on official git repository (https://github.com/riscv-software-src/riscv-tests/tree/master/isa) I found only **fence.i** test. I need similar test for **fence** instruction. (Do not ask why). What is the best approach to make the test for **fence** instruction? Is it enough to substitute **fence.i** for **fence**?